# Numbers on table name

Tags: database, numbers, naming, convention

Is it okay that I use numbers for table names in my database

For example

```
 create table `tbl_love143`;
```

Is it a good naming convention?

Comment: Depends on **WHICH** database system you're using.... each database has their own set of rules about naming...... but if the database allows numbers in table names - I don't see any reason not to use them, if appropriate. Just don't call your tables `table001`, `table002` ...... that would **NOT** be a good naming scheme!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database engine permits numbers, I see no reason not to use them. However, given your example of `tbl_love143`, does this mean you have 142 other 'love' tables? if so, there is something seriously wrong with your database design!

In summary, numbers are fine, but having multiple tables that store the same 'type' of information is not.